# Wordpress Gallery Border

Tags: html, css, wordpress, border

I'm wanting to add borders to gallery images. But in a chessboard effect so image 1, 3, 5, 7, 9... will be black and 2,4,6,8,10... will be white.

I've tried the following CSS and I've had no luck :(

```
#gallery-1:nth-child(odd) img {
    border: 3px solid #B8A8A8;
}
#gallery-1:nth-child(even) img {
    border: 3px solid #000000;
}

.attachment-thumbnail:nth-child(odd) {
    border: 3px solid #B8A8A8;
}
.attachment-thumbnail:nth-child(even) {
    border: 3px solid #000000;
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<dl class="gallery-item">
            <dt class="gallery-icon portrait">
                <a href="http://something.co.uk/ducfs/?attachment_id=9"><img width="120" height="120" src="http://something.co.uk/ducfs/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Events-1-IMG_4864-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="Events 1 IMG_4864"></a>
            </dt></dl>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
.gallery-item img:nth-child(odd){}
.gallery-item img:nth-child(even){}
```

instead of

```
#gallery-1:nth-child(odd) img {
border: 3px solid #B8A8A8;}
#gallery-1:nth-child(even) img {
border: 3px solid #000000;}
```

I think, it may work.

Comment: It worked! Just did exactly what you said! Damn typo :P Thanks :)